# How to implement an n-bit adder whose input vectors are represented in octal?

Tags: verilog

I'm somewhat stumped on this problem:

"Write a verilog module for full addition of n-bit integers. Let the parameter, the number of bits, equal 3.  Call this module from a test bench, and in the test bench specify the numbers to be added in the arrays.  Assign octal values to the X and Y arrays.  The carryin is 0."

And yes, this is homework.

I was able to write the module for the n-bit adder:

```
module addern(carryin, X, Y, S, carryout, overflow);
  parameter n = 3;
  input carryin;
  input [n-1:0] X, Y;
  output reg [n-1:0] S;
  output reg carryout, overflow;

  always @(X,Y, carryin)
    begin 
      {carryout, S} = X + Y + carryin;
      overflow = (X[n-1] & Y[n-1] & ~S[n-1]) | (~X[n-1] & ~Y[n-1] & S[n-1]);
    end

endmodule
```

I understand this component of the problem.  However, I'm not sure how to implement the octal number addition.  Is there a way in verilog to indicate that the arrays are holding octal values, rather than binary?

Is there anything like a typecast in verilog? For instance, `input (octal) [n-1:0] X, Y`, and do something likewise in the test bench.

Any constructive input is appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to; just take the bits of your overall number in groups of three.

Comment: Good point. So would I simply change by parameter `n` to 9? My only concern is how the problem is worded. For instance, farther down the page it says to explicitly set X to [0,1,3].

Comment: All they're asking you to do is assign an octal literal to X - `x = 9'o013`

Comment: That makes sense. If I do that, is verilog intelligent enough to add the numbers in octal, being that `parameter n = 3;`?

Comment: Octal, hex and decimal are just ways of visualising numbers at the end of the day they are binary when stored digitally.

Comment: I'm familiar with that, but I'm wondering how verilog will interpret the numbers. After all, if I pass a 3 into the vector X, is that in decimal, octal, or hex?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure I'm in the same class as you. I think what you need to do is create a hierarchical Verilog module and then assign your values there. That would be your testbench. for example if you want to make X you write input [n-1:0] X = 3'o013, or maybe it's X = 9'o013 if Oli is correct. you don't change n, but it's kind of like BCD where they are in groups and you have a certain amount of bits you can represent before it overflows.

Answer (score 0):

To help solve the problem thik about the question:
**Q)** How are numbers stored in digital hardware?
**A)** Binary, in digital logic we can only represent 2 values 1 and 0, but with this we can represent Integer, fixed point or floating point numbers.

Therefore digital numbers are base 2 (two possible values), while being able to represent any number. Other bases such as Octal (*base 8*) hex (*base 16*) and decimal (*base 10*) exist but these are just way of representing numbers, similar to the way binary just represents a number.

A decimal 1, is represented by 1 n all the bases, and when stored as binary they are all the same. An example of some values in verilog and there binary equivalents.

```
Octal    Decimal   Hex     Binary
3'O7  => 3'd7   => 3'h7 =>    3'b111
6'O10 => 6'd8   => 6'h8 => 6'b001000
```

Octal, Decimal and Hex in verilog are just representations of a binary format, a way of viewing the data. Since the low level electronics has no way of representing any thing other than 0 and 1.

The interesting thing about Octal and Hex is that they have a power of 2 values so they use an exact number of bits so an `9'O123` is the same as treating each Octal place separately and concatenating them together, `9'O123 == {3'O1, 3'O2, 3'O3}`. This is also true for hexadecimal values but not decimal (base 10) values, as 10 is not a power of 2 and does not fully occupy the number space.

This does allow 'Octal' ports to be created, **which are just 3 bit binary ports**:

```
module octal_concat (
  input  [2:0] octal_2,
  input  [2:0] octal_1,
  input  [2:0] octal_0,
  output [8:0] concat
);
  assign concat = {octal_2, octal_1, octal_0};
endmodule

octal_concat octal_concat_0 (
  .octal_2(3'O1), 
  .octal_1(3'O2), 
  .octal_0(3'O3),  
  .concat() //Drives 9'O123 which is also 9'b001_010_011
);
```